# Are quantifiers a type of logical connective?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Wikipedia defines quantifiers as an "operator".

The word "operator" means "operation" (a function) or "logical operator" (logical connective).

I also read that an atomic formula cannot have quantifiers.

Because atomic formulas are defined with the condition of having no logical connectives, I wonder if quantifiers not being allowed is because of this.

Is a quantifier a logical connective?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connectives and quantifiers are two different types of operators.

An n-ary connective is an operator which takes n formulas and gives a new formula.

A quantifier is an operator which takes a formula and a variable and gives a new formula.

Atomic formulas have no operators, so no connectives and no quantifiers.